# nginx proxy_pass SSL not working

Tags: ssl, meteor, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a meteor website at localhost:8080 and I have a nginx server that accepts secured connections.

The nginx server has the port 80 redirect the client on the port 443 and the port 443 should proxy pass to localhost:8080.

The issue is that when I go on http I get an error 503 and no redirect and when I go on https I get a timeout.

If I curl my localhost:8080 I get the correct page, so meteor works.

This is my conf file :

```
server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version

# this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

# HTTP
server {
    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html; # root is irrelevant
    index index.html index.htm; # this is also irrelevant

    server_name www.onlinefightingleague.org onlinefightingleague.org; # the domain on which we want to host the application. Since we set "default_server" previously, nginx will answer all hosts anyway.

    # redirect non-SSL to SSL
    location / {
        rewrite ^https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy; # we enable SPDY here
    server_name www.onlinefightingleague.org onlinefightingleague.org; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate

    root html; # irrelevant
    index index.html; # irrelevant

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/onlinefightingleague.pem; # full path to SSL certificate and CA certificate concatenated together
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/onlinefightingleague.key; # full path to SSL key

    ssl on;

    # performance enhancement for SSL
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    # safety enhancement to SSL: make sure we actually use a safe cipher
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';

    # config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
    # to avoid ssl stripping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_stripping#SSL_stripping
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    # If your application is not compatible with IE <= 10, this will redirect visitors to a page advising a browser update
    # This works because IE 11 does not present itself as MSIE anymore
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE" ) {
        return 303 https://browser-update.org/update.html;
    }

    # pass all requests to Meteor
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
        # on every applicaiton update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
        # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
        if ($uri != '/') {
            expires 30d;
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that that rewrite even compiles, since what it actually appears to be doing is rewriting https:// not rewriting *to* https.

So I think what you want for your rewrite is:

```
rewrite ^.*$ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
```

With respect to the 503, have you checked the error log? A 503 should always show up and give you a hint as to what nginx is attempting to do.

Comment: In the error log I only get a warning about the certificate being self-generate and I only got one time this error that I never got after that :

2016/04/22 23:50:17 [error] 5341#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/xmlrpc.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.248.160.136, server: www.onlinefightingleague.org, request: "GET /xmlrpc.php"

For now I still get an error 503 without anything in the logs.